# How to implement 4-way de-interleaving load in NEON using VLDn instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, simd, neon

For reference I'm looking at section 4-65 of http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/DUI0489C_arm_assembler_reference.pdf

I'm struggling to understand the reference guide, but I'm trying to load 4 sets of 4 floats into 8 different d registers (d6-d13) using interleaving as follows:

Memory at address r0 which I'm loading from (all 32-bit floats):
`[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p]`

```
d6 = [a,e]
d7 = [i,m]
d8 = [b, f]
d9 = [j, n]
d10 = [c, g]
d11 = [k, o]
d12 = [d,h]
d13 = [l, p]
```

I'm trying to achieve this using the following instruction but it doesn't seem to be working. From what I can work out, `a` is being placed in the right register and I'm expecting r0 to increase by 64-bytes (4 sets * 4 floats * 4 bytes-per-float), when in fact it's only increasing by 32 bytes.

```
vld4.32 {d6,d8,d10,d12}, [r0]!
```

Comment: I think Table 4-14 is saying that you can load into 4 `d` registers, but they can be contiguous or with a stride of 2 between register numbers.  Not that you can load into 8 `d` registers.  But I'm not familiar enough with NEON to be sure of what those multi-reg loads can do.

Comment: Ah that's correct! Thanks, I've figured it out now.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter pointed out, you can only load into 4 d registers at one time with this command. To achieve the desired interleaving pattern I had to do the following:

```
vld4.32 {d6,d8,d10,d12}, [r0]!
vld4.32 {d7,d9,d11,d13}, [r0]
```